# Angular js inline style color is not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css, angularjs, styles, inline

Hi I am trying to give color dynamically to `p` tag but for IE-11 browser it is not supporting how can I fix this issue,

```
<p style="color:{{userData.color}} !important;">{{userData.someText}}</p>
```

When I inspect the element it is coming like this in IE
Note: it is working fine in chrome, firefox..!

I tried with `ng-style="color:{{userData.color}} !important;"`

[image]

Comment: Use `ng-style` directive instead. `<p ng-style="color: userData.color">{{userData.someText}}</p>`

Comment: @Kavindra I tried it, not working but when I inspect element color is there but not rendering to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass styling object to **ng-style** `{color:userData.color}`

```
<p ng-style="{color:userData.color}">{{userData.color}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

**HTML**

```
<p ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" style="color:{{hex}}">color: {{hex}}</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hex= "#ff0000";
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hex= "#ff0000";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<p ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" style="color:{{hex}}">color: {{hex}}</p>
```